# If binding statement in knockout with view page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this `div` which displays a letter, but I want to add an if statement of when to show this div based on the following condition:

**if usersCount() > 3 then show letter**

```html
<div class=" header" id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter">
   ....
</div>
```

How could i add the if statement along with the text - expression statement?

```
data-bind="if: UserCount() > 13 then text:Letter"` ....??

var userViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
       _self.Letter = ko.observable(data.Letter);
    };

 var roleViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.UserCount = ko.observable(data.UserCount);
    };
```

Comment: I think you are trying to put too much conditional logic in your view.  By convention it should be in your view model.  Have you thought about creating a computed to choose which value to show and binding to that from your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Visible Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html). You'll want to create a property in you View Model to handle the logic of hiding/showing the div. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNdJk/) to demonstrate.

```
<div data-bind="visible: shouldShowMessage, text: Letter">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.Letter = ko.observable('Hello, World!');
        self.UserCount = ko.computed(function() {
            return Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
        });
        self.shouldShowMessage = ko.computed(function() {
            return (self.UserCount() > 13);
        });
     };
</script>
```

Comment: i added my viewmodels that i am using in my post- i am thinking since i have `text:UserCount()` it is displaying the number as a string so it won't be right `string > int` right?

Comment: UserCount needs to be one of the knockout observables if you're binding it. So if UserCount is a ko.observable() then leave off the (). Otherwise you need to make the UserCount a knockout observable that works for what you're using it for.

Comment: Thanks - i am adding the javascript to my file but because i have `shouldShowMessage` in a viewModel and `UserCount` in a different viewModel i am getting an error message stating that it can't read the property of the second viewModel?

Comment: Are you able to use a master view model like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/4qQDh/ ?